# How to check for two conditions using && operator

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to use 1 If statement to check that both values are not zero

```
if ((minvalue !== 0) && (maxvalue !== 0)) {
 // Both are not 0
 }
else
 {
 // Both values are 0
 }
```

I can get it to work by using two if statements

```
if ((minvalue !== 0){
   if(maxvalue !== 0){
   // Both values are not zero
}
}
```

But I'm not sure how to do it in one If.

Comment: Your first example should work if I understand you correctly. `if (minvalue !== 0 && maxvalue !==0)`

Comment: the first sample is "one if"

Comment: Your first snippet looks okay to me, except that the second part doesn't mean that both values are 0 (although that's possible), only that at least one of them is.

Comment: Your code looks correct. Did you check `minvalue` and `maxvalue` if the both a really not 0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will also work

```
if (minvalue || maxvalue) {
 // Both are not 0
}else {
 // Both values are 0
}
```

**Edit :**

If you example doesn't work, you should consider doing
console.log(minvalue,maxvalue);

Your code works, so that's your minvalue and maxvalue which are wrong. Might be strings

Comment: "*Both values are 0*" - how does that follow?

Comment: OP's code accepts NaN (as it's non-zero) but your code doesn't (NaN is false).

Comment: After edit: "*Both are not 0*" - how does that follow?

Comment: "OP's code accepts NaN (as it's non-zero) but your code doesn't (NaN is false)" I guess he use an integer

Answer (score 0):

Your first code block should be fine.  If you want to get a bit more clever about it you could instead test that the product of both values is not zero (as anything multiplied by zero will be zero).

```
const minvalue = 1
const maxvalue = 3

if (minvalue * maxvalue !== 0) {
  console.log('foo!') // foo!
} else {
  console.log('bar...') // [not hit]
}
```

Also, stylistically, it's considered bad practice to leave hanging curly braces.  Move your `else` and subsequent opening block curly brace up a line (as above).

Comment: `var x = Math.pow(2, -1000);` Now `x` is not `0`, but `x * x` is.

Comment: Yeah yeah, and `0.1 + 0.2 !== 0.3`.  This is JavaScript, not MATLAB.

Comment: Yes, and OP's code works correctly and yours does not.

Comment: Actually, OP's code _doesn't_ work properly, for exactly the same reason you called me up on my answer.  Suppose OP passes in `Math.pow(2, -1000000000)` as either argument?  As you pointed out _Now `x` is non `0`, but `x * x` is._  You're arguing edge-cases that only exist in scenarios where JavaScript is woefully ill-equipped to deal.